# Bios Settings and Hardware RAID configuration from Ubuntu MAAS

Tags: maas, raid, bios

Can we do the Bios Settings and Hardware RAID configuration from Ubuntu MAAS for HPE Servers?

Any pointers are highly appreciated?

Thanks,
Ashraf

Comment: HPE is moving all the config tools to RESTful API and RedFish There are HW level tools you can use against the iLO IP to configure BIOS/UEFI settings and RAID settings via RESTful API. See here: https://developer.hpe.com/blog/setting-bios-and-storage-controller-properties-with-redfish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAAS generally doesn't work with BIOS settings.  You'll have to configure bios and raid before adding the machine to MAAS.

That said, if HPE has a configuration utility that:

- runs inside an OS,
- that can reach back into the bios to make changes,
- that has a CLI,
- that can be downloaded using curl in real-time,

  you could inject it into MAAS using a commissioning script.  But all MAAS is doing is downloading and running a program. There's no BIOS-awareness built into MAAS.

Comment: Thanks James for replying. <br> You have answered about Bios settings. Regarding RAID config, the following link has RAID Device APIS like GET, POST, DELETE https://docs.ubuntu.com/maas/2.2/en/api.  <br><br> Just wanted to check if these will configure HARDWARE RAID?   <br>Thanks Ashraf

Comment: That's software raid. Maybe analogous to Microsoft Storage Spaces. Given the still-evolving nature of MAAS, I'd recommend configuring hardware raid before the node is commissioned by MAAS...or defer storage configuration to a downstream product like Ceph, LVM, Windows Storage Spaces, or some other software-based answer. Just my opinion, but I think MAAS is great at automation and improving quality of life during hardware deployment/reconfig. But best not to create too many entanglements between MAAS and your nodes.  If MAAS dies, you want it to be easy to rip out and rebuild.  ...continued...

Comment: Please dont get me wrong; I LOVE MAAS. But i think it's best to keep MAAS laser-focused on what it excels at - bootstrapping an OS on hardware.  In our environment, we do that...then turn the node over to puppet, juju, and/or bamboo for configuration and deployment.